# Appropriate timescales for an undergrad research project

Tags: research-undergraduate

I'm a sophomore in engineering in India, and I have an opportunity to take up an undergraduate research project to investigate the efficacy of deep learning for medical imaging. This is at a university with a top medical program. However, the data has just started being annotated and due to this, the project could take as long as 2 years (according to the faculty since CT data is pretty voluminous). There would be some periods of very less work, while some periods would need huge amounts of work in a week.

The main point of contact/research mentor would be a grad student, who in turn works under some professor. They are very experienced in the medical imaging field, but have just started venturing into AI. I have the chance to publish as a non-first author if the results are worthy of publishing.

I plan to apply for grad school right after undergrad. The possibility of publishing seems to be a great offer, but if it were to take 2 years from now to finish the project, I may not have a publication to include in my applications. I will probably have an LoR (preferably from the prof) and gained some research experience though.

My main question is: **Are undergraduate research projects on such long timescales (like 2 years) likely to stagnate and/or get abandoned?**

I'm not experienced with CT scans but 2 years seems a bit overboard to me for training and evaluating models, since most of the delay is coming from annotating the data.

PS: I do have the chance to get similar opportunities with smaller timescales later, but the potential impact of this project is high, and hence my personal liking for it

Comment: This seems more like a local question. The answer could vary a lot depending on the local traditions. For some, a single semester would be all that is available. For others, a longer period. Ask a professor involved in the project(s).

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- reduced to the main question on timescales

Comment: @Buffy I'm from India. Most of the professors who do such projects finish them within a year. If they are sanctioned for 2 or more years, they often publish intermediate results each year. It is possible that this project too has some intermediate results, but the general pace looks dreary to me at the outset

Comment: Thanks, I retracted my close vote. Are you being paid?

Comment: Undergraduates are not expected to finish projects, just work on them.  Your supervisor should provide long-term management.